# Apple ID is never remembered

Tags: apple-id, password, login, app-store-connect

Whenever I go to App Store Connect or any other Apple website where you can log in with your Apple ID, it always asks for my username and password, even though I always check the "Remember me" checkbox. It's been like this for months, ever since I can remember. When I go to my Apple ID profile page, all my devices show up as "Trusted".

It's the same for an Apple ID I use for App Store Connect at work, which is totally unrelated to my personal account - I check "Remember me", but 10 minutes later I'm logged out and need to provide the username and password again.

Is this just how it's supposed to be? Perhaps "Remember me" doesn't mean "Remember me" in Apple lingo? I've seen so many strange and misleading Apple error messages that I honestly don't know.

I'm using a normal Chrome window/tab (not in private mode) on OSx Mojave, and I don't have any extensions that delete cookies. Every other site with a "remember me" setting works normally, only Apples various websites forget me all the time.

Comment: Are you browsing in private mode?

Comment: Are you using any extentions that delete the browser cookies?

Comment: @fsb No, see my edit at the bottom of the question for more details.

Comment: @Daniil No, see my edit at the bottom of the question for more details.

Comment: If you create a new user account on your Mac and try from there: does it stick?